# Typescript assing async function result to a variable

Tags: typescript, asynchronous, promise, typeorm

I have a question and I know there is very similar question on there. And also i tried suggestions of them. But i couldn't solve my issue so i'm asking now. 
Firstly top-level await not working due to my typescript version. Don't suggest it please.

I'm trying to set my object's field according to database records. I will check my last 10 minute records of my object then if they are same i'll set a field isSame = true otherwise isSame = false. I'm making it with writing them to a .txt file and it works fine. But I don't want to create long txt file so i'll do it with db records.

 After create the object then i send my object to client.
I'm setting my objects field in my ts file like dummy codes:

```
object.id = 3;
object.prm = 5;
object.isSame = checkSame(); //checkSame is my function which decide whether true or not with log file
sendToClient(object);
```

But when I convert it db reads are async functions. So my variable will always be undefined. For show my problem i created a dummy project which has same issue.
This is main.ts line:

```
myObject.type = 0;
var persons = readDb("test");
myObject.persons = persons;
```

This is function in database:

```
export function readDb(personName: string) {
    getConnection().connect().then(connection => {connection.getRepository(Person).find({name: personName})
        .then(persons => {
            console.log(persons);
            return persons;
        }
        )});
}
```

If I do that I can get persons in the readDb function but not in the main program's flow. I need the return value in my main program's flow.
I tried:

```
var persons = null;
async function test() {
    const result = await readDb("java");
    persons = result;
  }

console.log(persons);
```

But person's still null. How can I do that? I need assign my variable on the main program flow. I already access it on my async function but I can't return it. (I tried return Person[], any etc. result is still same)
How can I get my async function return value on my main program's flow for assign it to variable?

Comment: As far as I can see, you don't return any promise to be awaited from `readDb`

Comment: Actually as i said "I tried return Person[], any etc." but I missed it when I was writing the question. I edited my question.

Answer (score 0):

Your `readDb` function doesn't return anything. You `await` for it to return `undefined`. This should do the job:

```ts
export function readDb(personName: string) {
  return getConnection().connect()
    .then(connection => {
      connection.getRepository(Person).find({ name: personName })
        .then(persons => {
          console.log(persons)
          return persons
        })
    })
}
```

Or using async/await style:

```ts
export async function readDb(personName: string) {
  const connection = await getConnection().connect()
  const persons =  await connection.getRepository(Person).find({ name: personName })
  console.log(persons)
  return persons
}
```

Comment: Actually as i said "I tried return Person[], any etc." but I missed it when I was writing the question. I edited my question. And also i tried your code but it's same. I see "null" in console.